# Parallelization of Gurobi with joblib on WLS License in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, gurobi, joblib

I want to do an analysis by running thousands of instances. Each instance solves several optimization models, including a final one using the result of the previous models. I want to parallelize all instances to multiple processors. I have a Gurobi WLS License, which should let me do it on a distributed system. I use joblib for parallelizing, with backend as multiprocessing since Gurobi does not support multithreading.
I attach below a minimal reproducible example

```
import numpy as np
import joblib
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from contextlib import contextmanager
from tqdm import tqdm
import gurobipy as grb


def instance_analysis():

    grb_env = grb.Env()
    

    n_players = np.random.randint(2, 5)
    player_values = dict()

    for player in range(n_players):
        num_extr = np.random.uniform(1, 2)
        with grb.Model(env=grb_env) as max_model:

            x_vars  = max_model.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,
                                        lb=0,
                                        name=f"x") 
            ### Constraints
            constraints = max_model.addLConstr(lhs= x_vars,
                                                sense=grb.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,
                                                rhs= num_extr, 
                                                name= "limit")
            ### Objective
            max_model.setObjective(x_vars, sense=grb.GRB.MAXIMIZE)
            max_model.setParam('OutputFlag', False)
            max_model.optimize()

            player_values[player] = max_model.objVal

    with grb.Model(env=grb_env) as min_player_model:

        p_var  = min_player_model.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,
                                        lb=0,
                                        name=f"p_var") 
        ### Constraints
        constraints = {ii : min_player_model.addLConstr(lhs= p_var,
                                            sense=grb.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,
                                            rhs= val, 
                                            name= "limit") for ii, val in player_values.items()}
        ### Objective
        min_player_model.setObjective(p_var, sense=grb.GRB.MAXIMIZE)
        min_player_model.setParam('OutputFlag', False)
        min_player_model.optimize()
        
        p_val = p_var.X

    grb_env.dispose()
    return p_val <= 1.5    


@contextmanager
def tqdm_joblib(tqdm_object):
    """Context manager to patch joblib to report into tqdm progress bar given as argument"""
    class TqdmBatchCompletionCallback(joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tqdm_object.update(n=self.batch_size)
            return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    old_batch_callback = joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack
    joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack = TqdmBatchCompletionCallback
    try:
        yield tqdm_object
    finally:
        joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack = old_batch_callback
        tqdm_object.close()


def main():

    with tqdm_joblib(tqdm(desc="Progress", total=20)) as progress_bar:
        results_dict = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=0, backend='multiprocessing')(delayed(instance_analysis)() for iter in range(50000))

    print(f"{round(sum(results_dict) / len(results_dict) * 100,2)}% of the instances have value less or equal than 1.5")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but I get an error

```
Progress: 335it [00:06, 51.31it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gpfs/home2/fmercurio/src/mrex.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()
  File "/gpfs/home2/fmercurio/src/mrex.py", line 77, in main
    results_dict = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=0, backend='multiprocessing')(delayed(cpu_instance_analysis)() for iter in range(50000))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/sw/arch/RHEL8/EB_production/2023/software/Python-bundle-PyPI/2023.06-GCCcore-12.3.0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1098, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/sw/arch/RHEL8/EB_production/2023/software/Python-bundle-PyPI/2023.06-GCCcore-12.3.0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 975, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/sw/arch/RHEL8/EB_production/2023/software/Python/3.11.3-GCCcore-12.3.0/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x1484674eb7d0>'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle 'PyCapsule' object")'
```

I think it is because too many environments called in a short time make the license full in little time. Is there a way to have one gurobi environment per joblib job?

Thanks!

Comment: Approximately how long does Gurobi take to solve each individual optimization model?

Comment: Hi Greg, I define very small Gurobi models, with solutions found in around 0.1 seconds (or just, very fast). On the last part of the simulation I have some bigger models (still, each one is solved in some seconds).